# How can I translate C code that copies the length of an integer value followed by a byte string consisting of the value into arbitrary bytes?

Tags: c, rust

I’m using this C code to encode several values into a byte string:

```c
unsigned char *buf = malloc(10);
*(unsigned int *)buf = 6;
memcpy(buf + 4, source, 6);
// Repeat for more values...
```

It copies a `uint32` with the length of the value followed by a byte string consisting of the value.

How can this be done in Rust? There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way (that I know of) to manipulate memory at arbitrary alignments and widths.

Comment: Use `Vec` as an allocator for bytes, if you really want to just deal with low level stuff, grab  pointers in appropriate locations of the vector and just use [`std::ptr::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.copy.html). Not an answer because I don't have a good example for unsafe code. You should prefer [`<[T]>::copy_within`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_within) since that's safe (and you guessed it, it does literally use `std::ptr::copy` after validating the bounds) and thus is less error prone, I guess.

Comment: Most code I've seen uses stuff like [`bytes`](https://crates.io/crates/bytes) in the back-end.

Comment: @trentcl That's right!. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[user4815162342's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820735/155423) provides a direct translation. Here is a more idiomatic Rust approach:

```
use byteorder::{BigEndian, WriteBytesExt}; // 1.3.4
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let source = [0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    let mut buff = Vec::with_capacity(10);
    buff.write_i32::<BigEndian>(6).unwrap();
    buff.write(&source).unwrap();
}
```

This works because the [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait is implemented for `Vec<u8>`.

Using the [`byteorder`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.3.4/byteorder/index.html) crate allows you to specify the endianness you want the length to be written with.

There are some differences to the C version:

- `write` would expand the size of the buffer as needed (although it will be more efficient if you create it with the needed size to begin with)
- `write` returns a `Result` indicating if there was an error. In this sample I chose to unwrap the result, which would panic if there was an error. However as pointed out by @shepmaster, the [current implementation of `write` on `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.46.0/src/libstd/io/impls.rs#L369-L372) only ever returns an `Ok` variant, so you could reduce the overhead of checking the result by discarding it like this:

  ```
   let _ = buff.write(&source);
  ```

Comment: [`Vec` does not return an `Err` from its `Write` implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.46.0/src/libstd/io/impls.rs#L369-L372).

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster. I am not sure it is so wise to rely on an implementation detail, but I have updated the answer to show it is possible to reduce the overhead of checking the result

Comment: No, I think that you are correct to use `unwrap` and not discard the error, I’m just saying that I think that the compiler might effectively ignore the `unwrap` because it knows it can’t fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is extremely low-level; it would help if you told us what high-level goal you want achieved, and we might be able to recommend an elegant way to do it in Rust.

However, Rust is a systems language, so it's definitely *possible* to translate your code into Rust, just take into account that it: a) won't be safe, and b) won't be elegant. By not safe I mean you'll literally need to use `unsafe` to allow unguarded writing to pointers, and figuratively that a bug might easily cause undefined behavior. And it's not elegant because there are usually nicer ways to achieve the same functionality.

With that said, here is a direct translation of the C code:

```
use std::alloc::{self, Layout};
use std::{mem, ptr};

fn main() {
    let source = [0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(10, mem::align_of::<i32>()).unwrap();
        let buf = alloc::alloc(layout);     // buf = malloc(10)
        *(buf as *mut i32) = 6;             // *(unsigned int *)buf = 6;
        ptr::copy(source.as_ptr(), buf, 6); // memcpy(buf, source, 6);
        // fill the rest of buf with something, otherwise UB on read

        // use buf...

        alloc::dealloc(buf, layout);        // free(buf)
    }
}
```

This kind of code is almost never normally written in Rust programs. It is used in special situations, such as when implementing a crate that offers a safe abstraction not yet covered by existing crates, and reviewed with utmost care. For example, the code written in this answer originally contained a non-trivial bug kindly pointed out by a commenter (now fixed). Also, the code doesn't check for allocation failure (but neither did the original C code in the question).

Comment: `*(ptr as *mut i32)` is unsound because, unlike `malloc`, `Vec::with_capacity` is not guaranteed to allocate memory of the maximum alignment, which would make the assignment an unaligned write.

Comment: @trentcl Good catch, I've now edited the answer to use `std::alloc` directly.

Comment: I would have suggested using `u32::from_le_bytes(6)` along with another `ptr::copy`, but admittedly `alloc` is the more direct translation of the C code.